# How to know if a resource file is not found without catching MissingManifestResourceException

Tags: c#, .net, resources, resourcemanager

I have .resx files located in different namespace for each client of my application. Say `Resources.FirstClient.Home.resx` and `Resources.SecondClient.Home.resx`. Most of the strings are common for each client so I want to introduce a default namespace `Resources.Default.Home.resx` that I can use if the strings were not found for the client.

The problem I have is that I don't know how to determine if a resource file is not found. (by example `Resources.ThirdClient.Home.resx` does not exist so I want to use `"Resources.Default.Home.resx` instead)

Right now, the only way I've found to handle it is to catch the `MissingManifestResourceException` thrown:

```
var resourceManager = new ResourceManager("Resources.ThirdClient.Home", typeof(ResourceFactory).Assembly);

string str;
try
{
    str = resourceManager.GetString("myString");
}
catch(MissingManifestResourceException e)
{
    resourceManager = new ResourceManager("Resources.DefaultClient.Home", typeof(ResourceFactory).Assembly);
    str = resourceManager.GetString("myString");
}
```

Is there a better way to know if the resource file is missing?

Comment: u can try use reflection to check whether that namepace and module is exist, but this try catch approach is much better than spending effort to workout the reflection approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We ended up loading instances of `ResourceManager` on the start-up of the application and keeping them in a Singleton instance, then using those instances when trying to get a string.

First, we load the resource managers to a dictionary of dictionaries, with the first key being the client name and second key being the name of the resource file (ex : `resourceManagers["ThirdClient"]["Home"]`). We also have a default value in the _tenants list :

```
var resourceManagers = new Dictionary<string, IDictionary<string, IResourceManagerAdapter>>();

foreach (var tenant in _tenants)
{
    var resourceDictionnary = typeof(ResourceFactory)
        .Assembly
        .GetTypes()
        .Where(t => t.IsClass && t.Namespace == "Resources." + tenant)
        .ToDictionary<Type, string, ResourceManager>
             (resourceFile => resourceFile.Name,
              resourceFile => new ResourceManager("Resources." + tenant + "." + resourceFile.Name, typeof(ResourceFactory).Assembly));

    resourceManagers.Add(tenant, resourceDictionnary);
}
```

We keep the `resourceManagers` dictionary generated in a singleton instance that is injected in our services using a DI container.

Then we use the injected dictionary to get the string or a default if it is not found :

```
public string GetString(string classKey, string resourceKey)
{
    if (!resourceManagers.ContainsKey(client) || !resourceManagers[client].ContainsKey(classKey))
        return resourceManagers[default][classKey].GetString(resourceKey);

    return resourceManagers[client][classKey].GetString(resourceKey, _cultureService.GetCurrentCulture())
        ?? resourceManagers[default][classKey].GetString(resourceKey);
}
```

From the tests we've done, this approach is about 1000 times faster than using a new `ResourceManager` and a `try catch` on every `GetString`.